# How Gmail makes it?

Tags: python, ajax, google-chrome, google-app-engine, gmail

I am developing service similar to banatag. During new feature developmnet I found unexplainable behaviour of Gmail(as I think).

I'll try to explain my question in picture:

1. Create tag(image that I will request). Now nobody requests it
   [image]
2. Add it by URL to email. Url of image http://eggplant-tag.appspot.com/request?FT1R3WECWNTM2ZGUDXRMA8VOXJ4F6TI4
   [image]
3. There are two new AJAX requests from page, **but there aren't to my domain**
   [image]
4. Looking for my service. There is request **from my IP**,  with Google User-Agent
   [image]

What does request this image(tag)?
I see two possibilities:

- page make AJAX requests to my service, that's why I see my IP. But in this case, why I couldn't see this request in Network tab of Developer Console?
- Google Image Proxy service requests to my service, but why in this case there is my IP in request?

My IP:

[image]

**[UPD]**
Add part of class that handles requests to image(tag):

```
...
request.remoteAddress = str(self.request.remote_addr)# save remote address
request.put()
...
self.response.write(simpleImageData) #write to body binary data of 1x1 transparent image
self.response.headers[ 'Content-Type' ] = 'image/png'
self.response.headers[ 'Cache-Control' ] = 'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'
self.response.headers[ 'Pragma' ] = 'no-cache'
self.response.headers[ 'Expires' ] = '0'
```

**[UPD 2]**

I used wireshark to found requests to my service, but there are  not any. That's why main question is how Google User Content simulate my IP address?

Comment: I don't see how this is related to appengine (or programming for that matter) aside from the fact that that is where you're hosting your page. If you want to know how the Google Content Proxy works i suggest you ask Google about it.

Comment: Yeah, it is not related to app-engine directly, but I add this tag because of I thought that there is small possibility that Google Image Proxy(GIP) and App Engine works together(in case of resuests from GIP to App Engine) and I saw side effect of it. What about programming, I think it nearby, because of it could be feature of browser requests or fail in my knowledges of network communication.

Comment: Well there are a bunch of browser features that could cause this. One is the preload of Chrome which buffers content even before you actually visit a website. The second is a standard feature where the browser sends an OPTIONS request to the server to determine the server's capabilities (but this shouldn't happen for simply GET requests). I think that it's the user content proxy though... and i have no idea how that works.

Comment: How are you retrieving the "remote address"? Maybe your library takes headers like X-Forwarded-For into consideration: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-Forwarded-For

Comment: @konqi I checked it on another browser(Tor, I think most features should be off in it) and had same result.

Comment: @TomTasche I learned code of couple of libraries(there is a lot of wrappers) and determine, that my library(webapp2) use os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR'] as remote address. It should be real IP, not from X-Forwarded-For header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deployed my app on my notebook, then I tried to repeat my actions.

Result confirmed my guess that Google Proxy and App Engine works together, and when Google proxy server requests my app, I see my IP.

In my experiment I saw IP of Google proxy.

Answer (score 8):

The workings of Google Image Proxy have been thoroughly analyzed on the web, e.g at https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-adds-image-caching-what-you-need-to-know and https://blog.filippo.io/how-the-new-gmail-image-proxy-works-and-what-this-means-for-you/ -- and the googleusercontent site is the cache/cdn used (among other things) by GIP.

The only relevance of Google App Engine might be how you've configured your `app.yaml` which you don't show us, i.e, is that image served as a static file, or via logic in your application code -- and, if the latter, does your code have any logging calls when it serves the image. From the limited data you show, I'd guess the former (so the file lives on, and is served by, Google's static file servers, not next to your app's code on your own instances), which would remove any mystery...

Comment: app.yaml will not help in this case. I add to question part of code that handles image requests.
The question is why I see my IP in requests, but there is no requests in developer console in Chrome.

Comment: @Alex I need your help regarding this gae + django question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086550/appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet-django