# AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet. Django

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to run django 1.9 on google app engine. Got the below error when trying to access API's through Google API Explorer.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/api/services.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cityguide.api.internal.categories import Categories
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/api/internal/categories.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cityguide.models import Category
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/models.py", line 8, in <module>
    class ContactDetails(models.Model):
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/db/models/base.py", line 94, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/apps/registry.py", line 239, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in check_apps_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
```

I already added

```
builtins:
- deferred: on
- remote_api: on
- django_wsgi: on

handlers:
 - url: .*
   script: mysite.wsgi.application

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'mysite.settings'
```

inside `app.yaml` file.

`wsgi.py` looks like

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "mysite.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

I tried adding `django.setup()` line on the top of `models.py` but it shows a different error.

```
ERROR    2016-02-01 10:03:02,918 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/api/services.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cityguide.api.internal.categories import Categories
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/api/internal/categories.py", line 10, in <module>
    from cityguide.models import Category
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/models.py", line 6, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/apps/registry.py", line 115, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 22, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 50, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from cityguide.models import Category
ImportError: cannot import name Category
ERROR    2016-02-01 10:03:02,919 wsgi.py:263] 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
    handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
    handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
  File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/api/services.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cityguide.api.internal.categories import Categories
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/api/internal/categories.py", line 10, in <module>
INFO     2016-02-01 10:03:03,000 module.py:794] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
    from cityguide.models import Category
INFO     2016-02-01 10:03:03,001 module.py:794] default: "POST /_ah/spi/BackendService.getApiConfigs HTTP/1.1" 500 -
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/cityguide/models.py", line 6, in <module>
INFO     2016-02-01 10:03:03,001 module.py:794] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis HTTP/1.1" 500 60
    django.setup()
INFO     2016-02-01 10:03:03,001 module.py:794] default: "GET /_ah/api/discovery/v1/apis HTTP/1.1" 500 60
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/gemini/projects/cityguide-backend/src/lib/django/apps/registry.py", line 78, in populate
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant
```

**Temporary solution for this problem:**

Seems like I need to open the home page first. So that it would loads the db since I made the homepage to return all the db table contents . Once the db lists  shown on the home page, we are ready to call the Google API Explorer.

Is there any way to refine this solution?

Comment: The error message usually means that `application = get_wsgi_application()` has not run. For instance if you import django models directly. I think there's some setup process needed to connect the python models to the database.

Comment: I'm not sure what happens in this step `File "/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 96, in LoadObject
    __import__(cumulative_path)`, but it must be a different wsgi.py from the one in the django project. Maybe `get_wsgi_application()` step hasn't run.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Does it work if you try running your site with Django's `manage.py runserver`?

Comment: @Louis no, it won't..

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You should first initiate django this way in your script:

```
import django
django.setup()
```

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/applications/#django.setup

You can also look at the Troubleshooting section of the link to see other possibilities to solve this aprticular exception.

By adding the above two lines at the top of `services.py` file solves this problem for me..

Comment: It might have to be added to this file. `/home/gemini/softwares/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py`

Comment: @HåkenLid pls see my update.. I have added a temp solution.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I can't suggest a better permanent solution. I've never used django with google app engine or the Google API explorer.

Answer (score -1):

In your script initiate django as:

```
from django_root_app.wsgi import application
```