# Run Django tests with nosetests

Tags: python, django, nose, django-nose

My python apps testing is performed on the remote server with command `nosetests`. I cannot modify the way tests are started nor can I add options to it. I have Django app with tests, but tests are not working properly.

My project structure:

```
project
├── README.md
├── setup.py
├── mysite
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
│   │   ├── tests.py
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
│   ├── mysite
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
|   |   ├── ...
```

Command `nosetests` is executed in `project` directory. I want it to properly run `tests.py` which has 2 Django testcases. I tried creating `tests` directory in project root and invoke tests with `DiscoverRunner`):

```
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'mysite.settings'
test_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)) # one level up
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(test_dir, 'mysite'))

class ServerTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_runtests(self):
        django.setup()
        self.test_runner = DiscoverRunner(verbosity=1, interactive=True, failfast=False)
        failures = self.test_runner.run_tests(['mysite'])
        self.assertEqual(failures, 0)
```

It works but the problem is all the tests are considered as a single test and wrong reports are produced by the server.

Another solution: if I add empty `__init__.py` to `project/mysite` nose discovers `tests.py` but the tests fail because `'Apps are not loaded yet'` which probably means I have to invoke `django.setup()` earlier but I don't know how to do it. I found a plugin for the nose which does it but I cannot install plugins or alter options on the remote machine.

Any ideas how to make any of my approaches solve the problem?

Comment: do the tests work correctly if you try to run them locally through `python manage.py test`?

Comment: @BartDur yes. They also work correctly if I run them with DiscoveryRunner.run_tests, but they count as one test then

Comment: Can u use `virtualenv` on the remote machine?

Comment: Are you able to run them using `nosetest` locally?

Comment: Are you able to add files to the root of the project?

Comment: Cannot use virtualenv, @JACKZHANG

Comment: Yes, I can run them locally, but only as single test @TarunLalwani

Comment: Yes, I can add files @solarissmoke

Comment: Hey @milos, did you solve your problem? Was any of the answers helpful?

Comment: Hey, sorry, I missed your answer, @JohnMoutafis

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Firsts things first, you should install and configure [`django-nose`](https://github.com/django-nose/django-nose) if you haven't done so already:

```
pip install django-nose
```

Then add it on your `INSTALLED_APPS`:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'django_nose'
)

TEST_RUNNER = 'django_nose.NoseTestSuiteRunner'
```

Now for the `nosetests` command to run correctly, you can create a folder named `tests` with the following structure:

```
project
├── mysite
│   ├── blog
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── models.py
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── mysite
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── settings.py
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── test_a_whole_class_of_methods.py  
│   │   ├── test_a_whole_view.py  
│   │   ├── test_one_of_my_methods.py
│   │   ├── test_another_one_of_my_methods.py  
|   |   ├── ...
│   ├── db.sqlite3
│   ├── manage.py
├── README.md
├── setup.py
```

**DON'T FORGET THE `__init__.py` FILE INSIDE THE `tests` FOLDER!!!**

Now when you run `nosetests` from the root of your project, it will run every test in the `tests` folder:

```
~ $ cd path/to/project
path/to/project $ nosetests
```

Comment: It tries to run every test in tests folder but gives "Apps are not yet loaded" exception

Comment: I assume that is because nosetests just tries to run tests as python files skipping django initialization

Comment: @milos This seems to be a problem similar to these: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086550/appregistrynotready-apps-arent-loaded-yet-django, https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/7mbk79/django_issue_appregistrynotready_apps_arent/ ?

Comment: No, it's quite different to my opinion. We should somehow run django.setup() before tests or something like that for tests to work properly. You suggested to change settings.py in your answer (INSTALLED_APPS and TEST_RUNNER) but I don't think nosetests uses these changes it just runs files

Comment: @milos If you want to use `django.setup()`, do it at the beginning of a test script, but because I am using `django-nose`, I am pretty sure that the cause is someplace else in your code...

Comment: How nosetests command knows it should use django-nose? I mean it just sees a bunch of tests that needs to be ran

Answer (score 0):

Since you can add files to the root of your project, you could try adding a `setup.cfg` file there that nose will look for when executing, and in it specify where to look for tests:

```
# setup.cfg
[nosetests]
where=mysite/blog/
```

(See the [documentation](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#configuration) for what parameters you can put here).

I'm not sure that this will work (it is possible that the command that starts nose has already specified a different configuration file to use), but it seems worth a shot.